# How to stop SMS sends if Mobile Number in Data Extension has an invalid format

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I have a use-case where-in SMS is sent to the number provided by the customer on a form. So if the customer provides a number with invalid format, the SMS should not go out.

What is happening is that if customer provides a number with invalid format, SMS is going out to customer's number available in Mobile Connect.

Is there a way to stop this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something to be taken care of **before** the SMS activity gets triggered.

- Add mobile-number format validation to the form, so it would not be possible to submit it with broken / wrong format.
- If you are using data import to MobileConnect to subscribe the people for a keyword,  then you could use SQL to separate the broken format numbers from the real ones.
- If the flow goes through Salesforce CRM, you could apply validation rules there. Or additionally some extra boolean that gets ticked if number is in wrong format.
- If you are using QueueMO API to trigger instant SMS sends, you could use validation at this stage and simply not process the numbers that are in wrong format.

Point is that once the number & message are provided to MobileConnect for processing, there are no configuration options (aside from Keyword subscription) you could use to prevent sending the SMS out.

Comment: Got it, thank you!